# Javascript Complex Grouping

Tags: javascript, grouping, nested-loops

I need help figuring out how I can loop through the Source Object to get the Output Strings.  I currently have some nested for loops but I wind up missing one of the combinations or I get too much. The Number of Categories and Filters will vary

Source Object

```
var Source = {Cat1:{Filter1:'f1',Filter2:'f2'},
              Cat2:{Filter3:'f3',Filter4:'f4'},
              Cat3:{Filter5:'f5'}};
```

Output Strings

```
Filter1 Filter3 Filter5,
Filter1 Filter4 Filter5,
Filter2 Filter3 Filter5,
Filter2 Filter4 Filter5
```

Comment: What is the expected result? cus you have a source object and an output string, but what is expected and what do you want to do with it.

Comment: The goal here from what I understand is to extract all the possible combinations of filters by picking 1 from each cat

Comment: Jonathan176 I have a question though: does the order of the output matters ?

Comment: Niels: The output Strings is the expected result. 
Aduch: The order doesn't much matter, I would like to avoid duplicate combinations though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, this will return Array of arrays:

```
function cartesianProduct(paramArray) {

  function addTo(curr, args) {

    var i, copy, 
        rest = args.slice(1),
        last = !rest.length,
        result = [];

    for (i = 0; i < args[0].length; i++) {

      copy = curr.slice();
      copy.push(args[0][i]);

      if (last) {
        result.push(copy);

      } else {
        result = result.concat(addTo(copy, rest));
      }
    }

    return result;
  }


  return addTo([], Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
};

var Source = {Cat1:{Filter1:'f1',Filter2:'f2'},
              Cat2:{Filter3:'f3',Filter4:'f4'},
              Cat3:{Filter5:'f5'}};

// var cats = [];
var filters = [];

for(var c in Source) {
  filters.push([]);
  for(var f in Source[c])
    filters[filters.length - 1].push(f);
}


console.log(cartesianProduct.apply(this || window, filters));
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks! That works.  I needed recursion that is what was missing and why it was throwing me for a loop :)